# Where did getchar() go in the second run

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, printf

I am trying to make an interactive socket communication client program which sends out messages to a server when user asks it to and also receives incoming messages on the same socket (once connected). Since these messages may arrive out of order, and I'm using non-blocking IO, I intended to check for a flag at the end of each select if user has interrupted the program to enter more options.

For the first call to `get_user_opts()` , the function runs fine and takes input from the user, but for the subsequent call, it does not wait for user input.

Running it in gdb says:

```
getchar () at getchar.c:37
37  getchar.c: No such file or directory.
in getchar.c
(gdb) 
38  in getchar.c
(gdb) 
37  in getchar.c
(gdb) 
_IO_acquire_lock_fct () at libioP.h:984
984 libioP.h: No such file or directory.
in libioP.h
(gdb) 
985 in libioP.h
(gdb) 
getchar () at getchar.c:41
41  getchar.c: No such file or directory.
in getchar.c
(gdb) 
get_user_opts () at ../testmain.c:444
444     switch(user_opt){
(gdb) 
597             printf("\n Unknown Option. Exiting\n");
(gdb) print user_opt
$1 = 10 '\n'
```

The relevant code segment is:

```
void get_user_opts(){
/***************************************************************************/
/* User Interactivity variables                                            */
/***************************************************************************/
unsigned char user_opt;

/***************************************************************************/
/* Initialization started. Ask user for options                            */
/***************************************************************************/
printf("\n************************************\n Options: \n\t1 - Open Connection "\
        "\n\t2 - Send Register\n\t3 - Send Unregister\n\t4 - Send Add Session" \
        "\n\t5 - Send Delete Session\n\t6 - Send Startup done\n"\
        "**************************************\n");

//  fflush(stdin);
//scanf("%c", &user_opt);
user_opt = getchar();

switch(user_opt){
    case '1':...
```

The signal handler toggles a flag which is checked at the end of each while loop. Suspicious that the signal handler might be the culprit, I tried making that condition true without the handler, and yet, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this actually two separate executions of the process or simply two separate calls of `get_user_opts()`?

Comment: 2 separate calls to get_user_opts() in a singe execution flow.

Comment: So the text "For the first run, the program runs fine and takes input from the user, but for the consequent run,..." was very misleading.  *Call*, not *run*, and *function* not *program*.  Moreover, GDB clearly shows that getchar() is called, so it is clearly not refusing *"to acknowledge the presence of"* `getchar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
user_opt = getchar();
```

to

```
user_opt = getchar();
while( user_opt != '\n' && getchar() != '\n' )
{
    // do nothing
}
```

This will remove any characters that follow that assigned to `user_opt` from teh line buffer - including the inevitable '\n'.

The console on most systems is line buffered, so `getchar()` will not return until an entire line is buffered (i.e. you have pressed ENTER); then you have at least two characters buffered  = the one you entered and the newline from pressing ENTER.  If you don't remove all buffered characters, `getchar()` will return immediately on a subsequent call.  The loop continues to get characters until it finds a newline, but checks `user_opt` in case the user simply pressed ENTER.

Comment: It works! But please explain how, I mean, why does this problem arise. even fflush(stdin) also did not solve this newline character problem. :)

Comment: @Anshul When you take input from the user, you hit Enter when you're done. You have to read that Enter key too, which the above loop does. It's undefined what `fflush(stdin)` does, so on your platform it didn't do what you expected it to do.

Comment: @Anshul : Added further explanation to answer. w.r.t. `fflush()`, it is not defined for input streams.  It flushes input in Microsoft's C runtime, but has no effect in GNU libc for example.

Comment: @Clifford Many thanks, I was confused about using fflush, I thought it had undefined behaviour for stdout. Thanks for correcting me there, and for the edit.
And thank you for the explanation too :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
unsigned char user_opt, tempChar;
while((tempChar = getchar())!='\n') user_opt = tempChar;
...
```

This will remove the newline character problem. It works because the `while` loop will make sure that the `newline` character is consumed by `getchar()` and does not create problems in the future.